# По какому принципу передаётся информация из seekbar Notification

Tags: android

Android: По какому принципу передаётся информация из seekbar Notification Media style? Нажатие кнопок передаётся через интенты с Actions (play, pause). A вот события перемещения ползунка песни не понятно.

Это требуется для отслеживания события перемещения ползунка для отключения/включения обновления Notification.
Понимаю что это событие вырабатывается в onSeekTo, но как оно туда попадает

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получать информацию о прогрессе, нужно установить обработчик на seekbar:

```
SeekBar sk = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);     
sk.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

    @Override       
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
       
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
     
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     

    }       
});
```

Comment: Чтобы обрабатывать эти события нужен доступ к seekbar, а к seekbar-у расположенному внутри notification доступа у меня нет

Comment: А notification вы как создаете? Можете добавить код в вопрос